# Is it possible to switch between custom and default transition in React Native using React Navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-navigation

Below is the transition config that I create so that I can pass custom transition from any screen:

```
const TransitionConfiguration = () => ( {
        // Define scene interpolation, eq. custom transition
  screenInterpolator: ( sceneProps ) => {
    const { position, scene } = sceneProps;
    const { index, route } = scene;
    const params = route.params || {};
    const defaultTransition = () => ( {} );
    const transition = params.transition || defaultTransition;

    return transition( index, position );
  },
} );

const navigationOptions = {
  navigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: background.color4,
      shadowColor: primary.color2,
    },
    headerTitleStyle: { color: primary.color1 },
  },
  transitionConfig: TransitionConfiguration,
};
```

As you can observe, I check if I have passed transition as a route param or not. If it's not passed, I pass a default function which returns an empty object.

Is it possible to switch back to StackNavigator's default transition if I don't pass transition config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after digging a bit into react-navigation's code, I found that there is a file called `CardStackStyleInterpolator` which provides functions to perform default transitions.

I just used the function `forHorizontal` exported from that file. I have not handled it for all cases or devices but I think it can be easily handled. Also, you wouldn't have to repeat the code for default cases.

Below is the snippet:

```
import DefaultTransition from 'react-navigation/src/views/CardStack/CardStackStyleInterpolator';

const TransitionConfiguration = () => ( {
        // Define scene interpolation, eq. custom transition
  screenInterpolator: ( sceneProps ) => {
    const { position, scene, layout } = sceneProps;
    const { index, route } = scene;
    const params = route.params || {};
    const transition = params.transition;

    return transition && typeof transition === 'function'
            ? transition( index, position, layout )
            : DefaultTransition.forHorizontal( sceneProps );
  },
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check [`TransitionConfigs.js`](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/src/views/CardStack/TransitionConfigs.js)

```
  function getTransitionConfig(

  ...
  ...

  if (transitionConfigurer) {
    return {
      ...defaultConfig,
      ...transitionConfigurer(),
    };
  }
  return defaultConfig;
```

You can see that when you define your custom transition configurator it will override `transitionSpec and screenInterpolator` props which are used to define the transition.

In your case by defining `screenInterpolator` this serves as one and only transition. If you want to define many including default ones please refer to [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43974979/react-native-react-navigation-transitions/43981835#43981835) and extend your custom one with default ones.

Meaning, your `screenInterpolator` should check wether there is a `params.transition` defined, if not fall back to one of the default ones.

Comment: Hey, I am not seeing the default transition. I feel that it defaults to my transition as I send empty object if transition config is not passed via params.

Comment: @rash.tay sorry, wrong statement from my side, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Hey, I am following the same post. And if you observe, you pass a default config in case a custom transition config is not sent via params. I don't want to pass a default config by myself. I want to fallback to the default transition config of the stack navigator. I can do that if I could know via some means whether I have passed transition from my route.params. Is it possible to not set the transitionConfig property at all if route.params.transition is undefined?

Comment: Not sure if it will fallback automatically to default transition. The `default` parameter I'm passing is just another custom one controlled by the app, not the react-navigation.

Comment: True. I don't wanna pass a custom one controlled by the app. StackNavigator has gracefully handled device specific navigation. I might end up repeating their code to achieve the same transition for different devices which I want to avoid. I'm trying to find a solution to avoid setting the transitionConfig property if route.params.transition is undefined.

Comment: @rash.tay Please let me know if you find a decent solution :)

Comment: Hey, I found a solution. Posting it as an answer.