# Is it possible to apply animation for react-router-native?

Tags: animation, react-native, react-router-native

I know that this question sounds like asking for suggestion which should not be here, But I am posting after searching a lot for my requirement.

I am using `react-router-native` for navigation which is great functionality wise. But comes to the animation part, it doesn't give the best user experience. [Official Documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/native/guides/philosophy) doesn't seem like providing any animation information.

Even in the google I found some articles([A shallow dive into React Router v4 Animated Transitions](http://A%20shallow%20dive%20into%20React%20Router%20v4%20Animated%20Transitions), [Animating Route Transitions with React Router](https://blog.logrocket.com/routes-animation-transitions-in-react-router-v4-9f4788deb964)) describing about animation for navigation but only for `react`.

Hence, Could anybody let me know that is there any way to apply animation for `react-router-native`?

Answer (score 0):

The standard place to start is exploring basic [Animations](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html). That said - have a look at one of the more developed transition libraries out there e.g. [react-native-transition](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-transition).

If it's specifically for just routing then there is a great answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43974979/react-native-react-navigation-transitions).

Comment: Could you suggest those other libraries like `react-native-transition`

Comment: Yes, unless you need more options and control than it provides - its great. It is easy to use and with a low threshold to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this animation library for react-router-native:
[react-router-native-stack](https://github.com/Traviskn/react-router-native-stack#readme)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [react-router-native-animate-stack](https://github.com/Taymindis/react-router-native-animate-stack)react-router-native-animate-stack

```
yarn add react-router-native-animate-stack
```

This is by default swipeable and you can customize the transition when move to next page.

[Screencast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWi4k.gif)

This is the package example running on expo snack

[example](https://snack.expo.io/@minikawoon/e0278e)