# Use react-native-router and have transitions between screens

Tags: react-native, react-router

Does anyone know of a way to have transitions between pages with react-native-router?

I know that this topic was previously discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48806300/is-it-possible-to-apply-animation-for-react-router-native), but there wasn't really a good solution that was found.

It seems like this is something that's easily doable with react-native-router-flux, but I'd prefer to not have to redo the routing and props.