# React-Native custom transaction animation each screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want custom transaction animation each screen
for Example A->B diffirent B->C.

I found:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43974979/react-native-react-navigation-transitions

But i don't know how to use it with: this.props.navigation.navigate('SearchVideo',{keywork:keywork})

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `react-navigation`, then customising screen transition can be done using `transitionConfig` of `StackNavigator`. Original source is [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html#modal-stacknavigator-with-custom-screen-transitions). However, it cannot know the previous screen, so you can only customise based on information of current screen.

An example with transition to B is left => right and to C is top=>bottom:

```
const myNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    A: { screen: A },
    B: { screen: B },
    C: { screen: C }
  },
  transitionConfig: () => ({
    screenInterpolator: screenProps => {
      const { layout, position, scene } = sceneProps
      const { index, route: { routeName } } = scene

      const width = layout.initWidth
      const height = layout.initHeight
      let translateX = 0
      let translateY = 0
      const opacity = position.interpolate({
        inputRange: [index - 1, index - 0.99, index],
        outputRange: [0, 1, 1],
      })

      switch (routeName) {
        case 'B':
          translateX = position.interpolate({
            inputRange: [index - 1, index, index + 1],
            outputRange: [-width, 0, 0],
          })
          break;
        case 'C':
        default:
          translateY = position.interpolate({
            inputRange: [index - 1, index, index + 1],
            outputRange: [-height, 0, 0],
          })
      }
      return {
        opacity, transform: [
          { translateX },
          { translateY }
        ]
      }
    }  
  })
)
```